# Configure store emails

Tags: magento2.3, email, order-email, smtp, adminnotification

I am looking to enable the sending of emails through the store using different email accounts in the case of general contact, sales and support.

So far I have been able to send emails by configuring ssmtp on my server with Ubuntu, but when I configure the different email addresses in the store panel, the emails do not go out, only with the account configured in the ssmtp.

Any ideas on how to enable mail delivery for certain addresses in my mail domain?